# Data validation - 4 Levels of validation based on another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m-sAEDuK-XzdBDqzaVcW5pq5Nqs4KzOcREMpqZhw6RQ/edit?usp=sharing) with data organized this way:

```
|ID|Date|hour|Type|bill to|Trip|Info|Tarif|Quantity|Price|
```

I'm using this script to have the first level of data validation in column |bill to| based on the choice in column |Type| and then the second level of validation in column |Trip| based on the choice of Column |Type| and |bill to|, all data come from the sheet "Tarifs - Data validation":

```
///////////////////Data Validation///////////////

var mainWsName = "1. Dispatching";
var optionsWsName = "Tarifs - Data validation";
var firstLevelColumn = 4; 
var secondLevelColumn = 5;
var thirdLevelColumn = 6;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tarifs - Data validation");
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2,1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,7).getValues(); 

function onEdit(e){
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName("1. Dispatching"); // ss = source sheet
  var srange = ss.getRange('f1');
  var sdate = srange.getValues();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();                
  var r = activeCell.getRow();                   
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();                
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName()

  if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 5){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r)
  }else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 5){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r)
    getInfo(e)
    getQuantite(e)
  }
  
  if(c === 4 && r > 5 && wsName === mainWsName && val !== ""){   
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2).setValue(sdate);
  }else if(c === 4 && r > 5 && wsName === mainWsName && val === ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).clearContent();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2).clearContent();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).clearContent();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,5).clearContent();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,6).clearContent();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,7).clearContent();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,8).clearContent();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,9).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  }
}

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){

  if(val === ""){
  ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
  ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
  ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else{
  ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
  ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
  ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
  var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
  var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn);
  

  applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);

  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(listToApply).build();//creo el dropdown
  if(listToApply[1] || null){
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  }else{
    cell.setDataValidation(rule).setValue(listToApply[0] || null);
    applySecondLevelValidation(listToApply[0], r);
  }
  }
}

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){

  if(val === ""){
  ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
  ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else{
  ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
  var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r,firstLevelColumn).getValue();
  var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
  var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
  var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn);
  

  applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);

  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(listToApply).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule).setValue(listToApply[0] || null);
  }
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell) {
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}



///////////////////fin validation///////////////
```

Now because I'm not able to add to the script the levels 3 and 4 for columns |Info| and |Tarif|, I try to write the applyThirdLevelValidation and applyFourthLevelValidation function to add to my onEdit(e) function,  I decided to do it "manually" using the filter function in sheets "Validation - Info" and "Validation - Price" where I use the filter function to have the lists for those level 3 and 4.

The problem is that if someone deletes a row, then I lose all my validation and I have to correct it manually.

Can someone help me to do those levels 3 and 4?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just in case I did something like this recently. Perhaps you can adapt my code for your task. Here is my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16MVMTE5Sv70_p9ei4nIOLfhX126PDlCDVU4aFvvWQJc/edit?usp=sharing The main difference between your table and mine, as far as I can tell, that is my table has no empty columns between the dropdowns. It will be pain to add them in my code (

Comment: Hi @YuriKhristich, your file looks perfect, it is exacty what I need, thanks for sharing that. I tried to adapt the code to my sheet but it's not working. The main issue is in the sheet "Tarifs - Data validation" I just want the data until column E and in the main sheet, I do not start on column 1 but on column 4.

Comment: I just tried to adapt my old code to your sheet. It's a pain, yep ). It looks like it works at last. To some degree. Try it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GZnWonXFWpEGyKVHcmoFBWqDb1dUfQcXBKC7cU6Gi9Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm glad you think it's hard :-) It is working well! the quantity column is the price though. I don't need the quantity and the price column as I put the quantity manually and the price is a formula based on it. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: So, does it need to change the code further? If you don't need to autofill the column 'I' you can change the line `var last_col = 9;` to `var last_col = 8;` And perhaps to add `+1` into the line #36: `sh.getRange(row, col + 1, 1, last_col - col + 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();` (if you want to clear quantity whenever you change a row). I just made the changes in the shared sheet

Comment: Hi Yuri, I tried the code but the tariff has no validation, I need to have also data validation.  Not sure why is not doing it. Also when I choose for example Type=DringDring Bill to = Migros Valais then trip= Migros Ritz, tarif is empty and I should have  a data validation neither, I should have here 2 choices: DringDring and CMS for the tarif

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247728/discussion-between-julien-and-yuri-khristich).

Comment: Try to change `last_col` to `last_col+1` in the line 58 this way: `if (col < last_col+1) set_data_validation(next_cell, list);` Actually it makes sense to rewrite the code anew from scratch. All these crutches '-1', '+1' doesn't look healthy. )

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. Finally, I don't know how to process that but in column G "info" sometime we need to overwrite what is in it meaning G should not have incidence on column H Tarif. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it needs yet another 'crutch'. I've changed the lines 37..54 this way. It should work now. Try it. The sheet by the same link. (Now the code is even more tangled :) )

Comment: Yes ! this is exactly what I needed. I'm trying now to integrate into your code the piece where I get the date in F1 starting at B8. Not sure where I can put this piece: `var srange = ss.getRange('f1');
  var sdate = srange.getValues();
  if(c === 4 && r > 5 && wsName === mainWsName && val !== ""){   
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2).setValue(sdate);`

Comment: Another problem, if I try to delete the Type Value, the data in the row are not getting erase anymore :-(

Comment: As for the date, I just added the function `add_date(e)` and updated the code (the same link). But it works from B6, not B8. Is it correct? As for the delete 'Type Value' I've added the line 41 `if (col == first_col && !value) ...` to clear current row